# Fetch data based on date in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have data in a collection named AuditReport as shown below.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("642aa674759fdc00019ddac5"),
    "Employee Name" : "a1",
    "Checked in" : "06/20/2023 06:11 APM"
},
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("642aa674759fdc00019ddac5"),
    "Employee  Name" : "a1",
    "Checked in" : "04/03/2022 10:15 AM"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("642aa674759fdc00019ddac5"),
    "Employee Name" : "a1",
    "Checked in" : "06/20/2023 08:12 AM"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("642aa674759fdc00019ddac5"),
    "Employee Name" : "a2",
    "Checked in" : "06/20/2021 09:19 AM"
}
```

And so on...

I need to fetch data of Employee(a1) on checked in date (06/20/2023).

```
db.getCollection("AuditReport").find(
    {
        "Employee Name" : "a1",
        "Checked in" : {
            "$eq" : "06/20/2023"
        }
    }
);
```

But it’s not giving the desired output.

Comment: Hi, your "Checked in" field is Date or string type? If you store as String type, it is not recommended especially when you need to query the data with date range etc. While why you match equal the date value with `Employee Name` field? And there is no `Template Name` in the attached documents.

Comment: hey m extremely sorry for wrong field name.I have updated now. Unfortunately "Checked in " field is string type .Is there any we can do this through scripts?

Comment: You should **never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw - and you used even localized format. Store always proper `Date` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, not recommended to store the Date as a string. As you will find difficulties when query the document by a certain date, or date range. Even if it is possible to convert the Date string to Date, you will find the query will be slower.

Approach 1: Since the `Checked in` field starts with this format: "MM/dd/yyyy", you can use regex expression to filter.

```
db.collection.find({
  "Employee Name": "a1",
  "Checked in": {
    "$regex": "^06/20/2023"
  }
})
```

[Demo Approach 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sgfHPGwxVRY)

---

Approach 2: Convert the date string into a Date and filter with the date range. Note that this requires aggregation operator, thus you need the `$expr` operator.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $eq: [
          {
            $getField: "Employee Name"
          },
          "a1"
        ]
      },
      {
        $gte: [
          {
            $toDate: {
              $getField: "Checked in"
            }
          },
          new Date("2023-06-20T00:00:00Z")
        ]
      },
      {
        $lte: [
          {
            $toDate: {
              $getField: "Checked in"
            }
          },
          new Date("2023-06-21T00:00:00Z")
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Demo Approach 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FECdRj-KZ_P)

Comment: On the other hand, I don't like the field with spacing. Even that you can query the field with spacing with: "$Checked in". Would recommend either change your field to PascalCase or camelCase like: "CheckedIn" or "checkedIn". Or using an underscore to replace the space. `Checked_in`

Comment: thankyou so much..never thought of use regex but its a great learning for me..tnx again

Comment: I noted all your suggestions and thankyou for your valuable  input. Also please suggest me how I can learn and master Mongo DB.